# how to code read or copy protect of micropython application code from ESP32 device

Tags: esp32, micropython

i have develpped an iot application using the micropython (my custome .py file). and uploaded to ESP32. i am looking of the way how i can privent other users to steel or copy my code are view my coder from the esp32 flash.
i try to buiild binary i could not sucessfull .

can some one hlep on this

i thry to convert py file to mpy file and some issue in esp32 to run the applicaiton . try to build custom binary (i am not able find good procedure for the same , for building applicaiton with main.py with other files and configuration)

Answer (score 1):

One option (as you already mentioned) would be to convert your application to machine code by using `MPY-CROSS`. Compile it yourself or from https://github.com/robert-hh/Shared-Stuff use tool MPY-CROSS.exe (if you are on windows) to convert your *.py to *.mpy.

When converting- check what exact mpy-cross parameters you need to use according to your hardware.

Comment: i am able to load and test app with mpy . is this the only way i can prevent user to read my application code? or any other option.